# Could not instantiate event handler. Type: Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer

Tags: c#, solr, sitecore, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

It was all of a sudden and it just stopped working. I have no clue what went wrong, what caused this to occur:

> Could not instantiate event handler. Type:
>   Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer. Method: ClearCaches (method:
>   Sitecore.Events.Event+EventSubscribers.Add(String eventName, XmlNode
>   configNode)).

I tried everything that would make it work but it didn't

1. Re-copied my Sitecore files from Sitecore 7.2
2. Re-Indexed my Solr
3. Created a completely new Sitecore project
4. Republished the complete site
5. Banged my head on the desk

Can anyone tell me the reason for this and what could be the solution. I am fairly new to Sitecore.

Updating the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote`

```xml
 <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCaches">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCaches">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied the files over from the correct version of Sitecore? Double check the version of `Sitecore.Kernel.dll` you have deployed and the version you have referenced in your VS project.

Comment: Hi Jammy. I am referencing the correct version.

Comment: Can you update the question with the XML for the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be wrong but could it be a simple spelling mistake in the handler registration in the events pipeline? I looked at the source code for SC 7.2 update 4 and there is no method called Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer.ClearCaches, how ever there IS a method called ClearCache.

Try to change the method name to ClearCache.

Cheers,
Bo

Comment: And `ClearCache` is also the default set in Sitecore config. Nice spot.

Comment: I tried refactor rename all the occurrences. But it didn't worked. Currently I just commented out the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` to stop myself being blocked.

Comment: One more thing to point out is: We have the same Sitecore project created for 2 different regions and they have different deploy locations. What surprises me is that the other deployed solution is working fine.

Comment: Hello Bo, since this is just a temporary work-around, can you suggest what else can be done here ?

Comment: Hi Todd, the HtmlCacheClearer class is a standard Sitecore class with the method ClearCache. Have you checked that the spelling is correct in the event hookups in the web.config? It should be <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">. You shouldn't need to refactor any of your code.

Comment: This seems to be weird. But now it is working without changing the class name as suggested by Bo. What I did is just uncommented the `publish:end` and `publish:end:remote` in the Web.config. I worked for couple of days by commenting these items. but now its working. This is really weird. But I will accept this answer so anyone can try this as well as what I did.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but I encountered a problem with the `HtmlCacheClearer` a few months back. Turns out it has a dependency on a legacy Lucene index called `__System`.

If that index get corrupted, it can cause some unexpected results. My situation wasn't exactly the same as yours but the fix simple and non-invasive. So it might be worth trying.

Just delete the `__System` index from you datafolder (it doesn't contain anything that needs to be kept).

I wrote a [blog post about this issue](http://sitecoreskills.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/sitecore-html-cache-doesnt-clear.html).

Comment: Hi Martin. I deleted the __System file from my data folder, but still its not working.